# angularjs $resource and one-to-many relationship

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

what is the right way to use ngResource for a complex data model?
There are countless one-table examples out there, but little to nothing covering 1:n and m:n relationships.

Assuming a simple 'parent' 1->n 'child' relationship, and the entry point is always through parent: is it necessary to create a $resource for parent and child, and call save() on the child for each time a new related child is created, passing the parent_id? Or did my way of thinking not arrive in the Angular world yet, and I should try to save() the parent only having ngResource taking care of the rest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ngResource is great but doesn't 'really' handle relationships and might be lacking a few things you need. What you have proposed - "create a $resource for parent and child, and call save() on the child for each time a new related child is created, passing the parent_id" - would be correct; however I would strongly recommend looking at either [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) or [Restmod](https://github.com/platanus/angular-restmod)

Both are great and there are some other ones out there too. My personal recommendation for be Restmod as I find it handles relationships better.

Comment: OK I thought so, wonder if it's even better to take the $http road for sake of flexibility. I'm not convinced to hook up to an external dependency for a very centric requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`$resource` is just another implementation of a [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) data store paradigm through HTTP requests.  There are many references out there on how to manage relationships between NoSQL entities (for example, [many to many relationship with nosql (mongodb and mongoose)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25101386/584846))

Comment: I wasn't aware that this is already considered NoSQL terrain, but see it more like a kind of object relational mapping. My backend is SQLAlchemy / Flask, and the relational data model is key to the application. Thanks for the direction, I will look into your suggestion more closely.